# Read txt file and get value of one line with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one `input.txt` file that have 3 columns like this:

```
1   0   0
2   8   8
3   272 280
4   462 742
5   702 1,444
6   990 2,434
7   1,326   3,760
8   1,691   5,451
9   2,200   7,651
10  2,640   10,291
...
```

I need a function (jQuery or javascript) to find a line on my `input.txt` and return to me the line that have the value in third column!

**example:**

HTML file

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
        var numberX = document.getElementById('id_x').value;
        //FUNCTION
          //var result = return of the function;
</script>
```

If `numberX = 3,760` , the function open my file, check all last column until find the number and return 7, so `result = 7`

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Sure this is possible, and I'm sure there's a great reason why you're using a text file as a flat file database... but why not an actual database, or at least a CSV?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing myself @cchambers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = null;

xhr.open("GET", "input.txt", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        data = xhr.responseText.split('\n');
        data = data.map(function(row) {
            return row.split(/\s+/);
        });
    }
};
xhr.send();

var getRecord = function(lastValue) {
    return data.find(function(row) {
        return row[2] === lastValue;
    })[0];
};
```

You would use it like so:

```
getRecord('3,760')
```

Comment: i did not understand how you choose the line! and why are u calling get Record('3,760')?

Comment: It sounded like you wanted to retrieve the row number based on the last number in the row. getRecord function does just that: it looks through all lines to find the one that ends in the passed number. If you call getRecord('10,291'), it will return 10. If I misunderstood your question, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to find a way to read your file. Try it with XMLHttpRequest.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "input.txt", false);
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You real files with `XMLHttpRequest` object and process the result as string.

I have a quick plunker demo.

```
var value = '3,760';
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'data.txt');
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var rows = text.split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var columns = rows[i].split(' ');
      for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
        if (columns[j] == value)
          alert(columns[0]);
      }
    }
  }
}
xmlhttp.send();
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/5TlTltp0TaZi98IPF8Ii?p=preview